# Why is Eclipse Luna dark theme ugly?

Tags: 12.04, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse luna ships with an integrated [dark theme](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/luna), I downloaded Eclipse CDT and deleted my workspace to reset Eclipse configuration.

I switched to the [dark theme](https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme) and restarted Eclipse; the UI doesn't look like expected:
[image]

I also have checked for updates within Eclipse (no update found)
The theme is supposed to look like [the screenshots in the link](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/11/dark-eclipse-ships-with-eclipse-luna/).

Comment: It seems this is answered on Stackoverflow. The problem isn't specific to Ubuntu or Linux. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470710/eclipse-luna-dark-theme-not-completely-dark-like-pictures

Comment: This fixes the text editor but not the unreable buttons

Comment: I'm too lazy to copy this as an answer. In the mean time: does this guide work for you? http://mihai-nita.net/2013/09/19/dark-eclipse/

Comment: No it doesn't, I can't reproduce the problem on an other Ubuntu install; something must be corrupted on my system

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Fix text editor colors:

Help > Eclipse Marketplace > Search for "Eclipse Color Theme" and install it.

Then go to:
Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance > Color Theme

### Fix text boxes colors:

Open a terminal and run

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

Then start Eclipse :

```
eclipse
```

The user interface should be fixed. If this worked for you edit the eclipse launch script for more convenience:

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/eclipse
```

Add

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

Before:

```
ECLIPSE=/usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
```

Source:
https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/issues/73

Comment: export SWT_GTK3=0 (and = 1) is not working for me. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

The editor issue should be fixed with Eclipse 4.4.1. On of the Eclipse plug-ins was affecting the styling of the editor.

Comment: I'm on Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1). It's not fixed.

Comment: For reference, the problem is not yet fixed on 4.4.1, but until a proper fix comes through, [Toshihiro's workaround](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438175#c6) seems to work (although scrollbars and buttons are still kinda crappy).

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with a dark theme also. You can try the following:

go to: Windows>Preferences>General>Appearance

and disable: Enable Theming

It might help!