# Full dark theme for eclipse Luna in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, themes, eclipse

I read this question : [Why is Eclipse Luna dark theme ugly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490693/why-is-eclipse-luna-dark-theme-ugly)

And i followed what guari told us to do. I create a `dark.sh` in a same directory with `eclipse` executeable. This is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0 //0 or 1 not working
./eclipse
```

So i run the dark.sh from the terminal, and eclipse will be run from it. However, my **side bar** is still looking ugly (white, not dark).

What should i do?

UPDATE

I use `dark` theme (default from the eclipse)#!/bin/bash

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
./eclipse
```

But it still not working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

May be you need to try this plugin from eclipse market place -- [Eclipse Color Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-color-theme#.VGQVsnWUfqM)

After installing Eclipse Color Theme you have to go to:

```
Preferences -> Appearance -> Color Theme,
```

Then select the whatever theme you like...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but my current problem is in the side bar

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.kaibader.de/fix-eclipse-luna-display-on-ubuntu-14-04). There, @Kai suggests:

`export SWT_GTK3=0
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0`

Comment: You again :) Thanks a lot, i will try this later (and will accept your answer)

Comment: Sorry, the code is not working...but people in the blog said its working...maybe i did something wrong somewhere? I updated my question, please kindly check it. Thanks