# export SWT_GTK3=0 on terminal, does it effect your system?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-terminal, eclipse, gtk

This question is related to my other question : [Full dark theme for eclipse Luna in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546828/full-dark-theme-for-eclipse-luna-in-ubuntu-14-04)

So, i should run `export SWT_GTK3=0` on a `sh` script for eclipse, but i mistakenly run it from my ubuntu's `terminal`.

I dont feel something changed for now, but i would like to make sure my system will be OK since i will need it in the near future.

Does running `export SWT_GTK3=0` dangerous?

What does it do?

How to **reset** `SWT_GTK3` to its **default** value?

Thanks  a lot for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the only thing you did was running `export SWT_GTK3=0` then you did nothing permanent. What the command does is to set an environment variable `SWT_GTK3` and set its value to 0 for that terminal session only. If you close the terminal window and open a new one it will be gone or reset.

If you want to unset it in the current terminal window you can also do: `unset env SWT_GTK3`.

If you want to see the current value of an env. variable: `echo $SWT_GTK3` or for example to see your current PATH variable `echo $PATH`.

Comment: This, except that it sets its value to 0, not 3

Comment: Thanks a lot.@tigerjack89 Thanks, what do you mean? So if i run export SWT_GTK3=0, it will be permanent?

Comment: @BlazeTama no, I just pointed out that the value of the variables `SWT_GTK3` is actually 0, not 3 as suggested by Hami. Also, the export is not permanent: it marks a variable as "to be exported", so all the child programs of the parent program can see that environment variable. In your case, it is visible only to eclipse if you run it in the same shell. Indeed, if you run `echo $SWT_GTK` in the same shell where you execute the `export`, it returns 0; if you open another shell and type the same command, it returns an empty line.

Comment: @tigerjack89 oops, thanks for the correction. And Blaze_Tama no it will not be permanent, I just typed 3 instead of 0, the rest is correct (I hope :) ).

Comment: @tigerjack89 Just to clarify, so if i run export SWT_GTK3=0 in the terminal, it means the terminal is the shell, so if i exit the terminal, the export will be no more?

Comment: yes, the export will be deleted. Also, take a look at these links for a detailed difference between shell and terminal http://askubuntu.com/questions/111144/are-terminal-and-shell-the-same
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con